# Ubuntu Installation, GRUB to USB

Tags: grub2

I have one HDD with two volumes on a single volume group. I plan to mount / on one volume, and /home on the other. What I also want to do is install the bootloader (GRUB) to a USB drive instead of on the HDD. But during the Ubuntu installation, I can't see how it's done. Please advise.

Comment: I already tried that. I assumed I was doing it wrong because I get the error:" No root file system is defined

Please correct this from the partitioning menu"

Comment: Obviously, you need to define the root file system as well. I suggest going through the answers carefully several times, untill you clearly understand the steps.

Comment: mikewhatever i love you. Finally got the thing to flippin work. It's only took me about 100 failed attempts over 2 days, totalling 7 hours of pain lol. I'm well happy it's actually working though!! cheers for the tips. I don't suppose you know how you can get this working with encryption do you? I do know GRUB supports encryption.